# jQuery unbind event scroll

Tags: jquery

I have some code from a core plugin. There I get a resize for navbar on scroll.
I can't access the core directly, so I use `jQuery(window).unbind('scroll');` and works. The problem is that I also have a `getScrollTop` event and now is disabled.

```
! function(e) {
    "use strict";
    e.fn.cmsmastersFixedHeaderScroll = function(o) {
        var i = {
                headerTop: ".header_top",
                headerMid: ".header_mid",
                headerBot: ".header_bot",
                navBlock: "nav",
                navList: "#navigation",
                navTopList: "#top_line_nav",
                respNavButton: ".responsive_nav",
                respTopNavButton: ".responsive_top_nav",
                fixedClass: ".fixed_header",
                fixedClassBlock: "#page",
                respHideBlocks: "",
                maxWidthMid: 1024,
                maxWidthBot: 1024,
                changeTopHeight: !0,
                changeMidHeight: !0,
                mobileDisabled: !0
            },
            t = this,
            a = {};
        a = {
            init: function() {
                a.options = a.o = e.extend({}, i, o), a.el = t, a.vars = a.v = {}, a.v.newTopHeight = 0, a.v.newMidHeight = 0, a.setHeaderVars(), a.startHeader()
            },
            setHeaderVars: function() {
                a.v.headerMidString = a.o.headerMid, a.v.headerTop = a.el.find("> " + a.o.headerTop), a.v.headerMid = a.el.find("> " + a.v.headerMidString), a.v.headerBot = a.el.find("> " + a.o.headerBot), a.v.respNavButton = a.el.find(a.o.respNavButton), a.v.respTopNavButton = a.el.find(a.o.respTopNavButton), a.v.respHideBlocks = e(a.o.respHideBlocks), a.v.fixedClassBlock = e(a.o.fixedClassBlock), a.v.navListString = a.o.navList, a.v.navTopListString = a.o.navTopList, a.v.navBlockString = a.o.navBlock, a.v.navBlock = a.el.find(a.v.navListString).parents(a.v.navBlockString), a.v.navTopBlock = a.el.find(a.v.navTopListString).parents(a.v.navBlockString), a.v.midChangeHeightBlocks = e(a.v.headerMidString), a.v.midChangeHeightBlocksResp = e(a.v.headerMidString), a.v.topHeight = 0, a.v.midHeight = a.v.headerMid.attr("data-height"), a.v.win = e(window), a.v.winScrollTop = a.v.win.scrollTop(), a.v.winMidScrollTop = a.v.winScrollTop - a.v.topHeight, a.v.isMobile = "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement
            },
            startHeader: function() {
                a.v.headerTop.length > 0 && (a.v.topHeight = a.v.headerTop.attr("data-height")), a.attachEvents(), a.v.win.trigger("scroll")
            },
            attachEvents: function() {
                a.v.respNavButton.bind("click", function() {
                    return a.v.respNavButton.is(":not(.active)") ? (a.v.navBlock.css({
                        display: "block"
                    }), a.v.respHideBlocks.css({
                        display: "none"
                    }), a.v.respNavButton.addClass("active")) : (a.v.navBlock.css({
                        display: "none"
                    }), a.v.respHideBlocks.css({
                        display: "block"
                    }), a.v.respNavButton.removeClass("active")), !1
                }), a.v.respTopNavButton.bind("click", function() {
                    return a.v.respTopNavButton.is(":not(.active)") ? (a.v.navTopBlock.css({
                        display: "block"
                    }), a.v.respHideBlocks.css({
                        display: "none"
                    }), a.v.respTopNavButton.addClass("active")) : (a.v.navTopBlock.css({
                        display: "none"
                    }), a.v.respHideBlocks.css({
                        display: "block"
                    }), a.v.respTopNavButton.removeClass("active")), !1
                }), a.v.win.bind("scroll", function() {
                    cmsmasters_media_width() > a.o.maxWidthMid && (a.getScrollTop(), a.headerTransform())  // IF I comment this line works, but still I don't want to change core code.
                }), a.v.win.bind("resize", function() {
                    a.v.headerBot.length > 0 ? a.headerResize(a.o.maxWidthBot) : a.headerResize(a.o.maxWidthMid)
                })
            },
            getScrollTop: function() {
                a.v.winScrollTop = a.v.win.scrollTop(), a.v.winMidScrollTop = a.v.winScrollTop - a.v.topHeight
            },
            headerTransform: function() {
                if (a.v.fixedClassBlock.hasClass('fixed_header')) {
                    a.v.winScrollTop < a.v.topHeight ? (a.v.headerMid.removeClass("header_mid_scroll"), a.v.headerBot.removeClass("header_bot_scroll"), a.v.newTopHeight = a.v.topHeight - a.v.winScrollTop, a.v.headerTop.css({
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        height: a.v.newTopHeight + "px"
                    }), a.v.winScrollTop <= 3 && a.v.headerTop.css({
                        overflow: "inherit"
                    }), a.v.midChangeHeightBlocks.css({
                        height: a.v.midHeight + "px"
                    })) : (a.v.headerTop.css({
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        height: 0
                    }), a.v.winMidScrollTop < a.v.midHeight / 3 ? (a.v.headerMid.removeClass("header_mid_scroll"), a.v.headerBot.removeClass("header_bot_scroll"), a.v.newMidHeight = a.v.midHeight - a.v.winMidScrollTop) : (a.v.headerMid.addClass("header_mid_scroll"), a.v.headerBot.addClass("header_bot_scroll"), a.v.newMidHeight = a.v.midHeight / 1.5), a.v.midChangeHeightBlocks.css({
                        height: a.v.newMidHeight + "px"
                    }))
                }
            },

        }, a.init()
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by unbinding scroll? This feels like the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: On scroll navbar changes height, but I don't want that. With my code I fix that, but turns off all scroll events getScrollTop  is also disabled, and I don't want that.